# AppStore's screenshot gallery in html?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, touch, iphone-web-app

I'm trying to do the screenshot gallery of an app from the AppStore but in a web app in html.

I've actually get it but the problem is that it scrolls REALLY slow.

To do the touch/swipe functions I've used the code from here:

http://quirksmode.org/m/tests/scrollayer.html

In the example, the div's are scrolled smoothly but not in my site with my div's...

Does anyone know what can be happening? Does anyone know a proper way to do it?

This is my (under-developement) site:

http://www.actec.cat/iphone/#projectes_pre

I'm testing it in an iPhone 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved using webkit transforms (translate3d) instead of using javascript.

The problem was that javascript was taking care of moving the object.

For example, I was using:

```
testElement.style.marginLeft="newposition px";
```

That was painfully slow in iOS devices.

Now I use:

```
testElement.style.webkitTransform='translate3d("newposition px",0,0);
```

And it works as smooth as it should.

Comment: You should detail the answer a little for future reference, and accept it.